# There is a long delay before an MP4 video will start in flowplayer

Tags: streaming, delay, flowplayer

Flowplayer at my site is working fine with (.flv) format, but for (.mp4) format it first downloading the whole file and then start streaming. Any solution? Will I have to make some changes in setting of flowplayer or there is even a solution exists for this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, fortunately found the reason and solution:

> With the release of the Flash Player 9 Update that supports H.264, we can now play a subset of H.264 movie files. The problem is most of the H.264 files have the index at the end of the file which for progressive download means you have to download the whole file before you can start watching any of the video.

There is also an [Air application - QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/) written by Renaun Erickson which fixes the problem. That works!

Comment: MP4 FastStart for windows users, same solution