# Flowplayer: how to convert m2v file to mp4 and make it streaming-able

Tags: macos, streaming, h.264, mp4, flowplayer

I have serious problem to identify my problem, so I'll describe it.

I'm storing mp4 files on Azure Blob Storage and displaying them with `Flowplayer 3.2.11`, unfortunately some of my videos doesn't stream but waiting for total download before the start (the same as in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12795210/1066240)).

I tried some programs and only QuickTime Player prepared the correct file, unfortunately it doesn't allow to change more advanced setting of the output file. Also I tried [Macroplant Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/), however created file doesn't stream.

In every test I used `H.264` codec and when checking the details of the created files in different programs they looks exactly (or almost exactly) the same.

So the final question is: is that something obvious I've missed or I need to test another programs (and which do you recommend?)

Comment: Need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532494/azure-and-live-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of searching and writing the question... I found an answer :) funny

> With the release of the Flash Player 9 Update that supports H.264, we can now play a subset of H.264 movie files. The problem is most of the H.264 files have the index at the end of the file which for progressive download means you have to download the whole file before you can start watching any of the video.

There is also an [Air application - QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/) written by Renaun Erickson which fixes the problem. That works!